# Python How to compute multiple averages from a single column, selecting the rows to average based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

**[EDIT: Rewritten question at bottom]**

I'm trying to figure out how to compute "partial-column" averages and counts rather than using all the values. In pseudo-SQL, I want to `SELECT` all values `WHERE id = 10`, then = 20, etc. I'm assuming there is a pythonic (pandastic?) way to do this without using for loops.

Example: `df` has 3 columns and thousands of rows: `case`, `id`, and `value`. Case is unique, id can be repeated, value is numeric.

```
case    id  value
1       10  100
2       10  500
3       20  200
4       20  150
5       20  125
```

I want to count the values and compute the averages of the values for each `id` and put them in new columns . . .

```
case    id  value   n_vals  av_val
1       10  100     2       300
2       10  500
3       20  300     3       200
4       20  150
5       20  150
```

. . . then delete `case` and `value` and keep only one row for each id (which are now unique):

```
id  n_vals  av_val
10  2       300
20  3       200
```

I know how to find `len` and `mean` for the entire column, but not sure how to do it for partial columns like this.

---

**[REWRITTEN QUESTION]:**

I have a df with 20000265 obs in 7 variables. `case` are unique, `Id` can repeat.:

```
case        Id      title           n_words n_chars rating  rating2
20000260    131258  The Pirates     2       11      2.5     2.5
20000261    131258  The Pirates     2       11      3.5     3.5
20000262    131258  The Pirates     2       11      4.5     4.5
20000263    131260  Rentun Ruusu    2       12      3       3
20000264    131260  Rentun Ruusu    2       12      5       5
20000265    131262  Innocence       1       9       4       4
```

I want to calculate the number of ratings and the average rating for each `Id`. These values are added to the df as `n_ratings` and `av_rating`, replacing `rating` and `rating2`, aggregated on a single row for each `Id`. I want to keep all other columns, producing something like this:

```
case        Id      title           n_words n_chars n_ratings   av_rating
20000260    131258  The Pirates     2       11      3           3.5
20000263    131260  Rentun Ruusu    2       12      2           4
20000265    131262  Innocence       1       9       1           4
```

Based on @U9_Forward's answer below, I have tried this:

```
df = 
    (df.
        groupby('Id', as_index = False).
        agg({'rating':'count', 'rating2':'mean'}).
        # rename(columns = {'rating':'n_ratings', 'rating2':'av_rating'}))
        rename(columns = {'Id':'Id', 'title':'title',
                      'num_words':'num_words', 'num_chars':'num_chars',
                      'rating':'n_ratings', 'rating2':'av_rating'}, axis=1))
```

However, this is retaining only the 3 columns (`Id`, `n_ratings`, `av_rating`) that were used in the `groupby().agg()` pipe, e.g.:

```
0   1   49695       3.921240
1   2   22243       3.211977
2   3   12735       3.151040
```

I tried including all col names in the `rename()` dict, but got the same result.

Two questions:

1. Is there a parameter for `agg()` or another way to achieve the
   desired result?
2. I got a FutureWarning in Jupyter and have read that
   using a dictionary with `rename()` is deprecated or soon will be. What is
   the new preferred way to rename cols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
print(df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'case':'count','value':'mean'}).rename({'case':'n_vals','value':'av_val'},axis=1))
```

And the output is:

```
   id  n_vals  av_val
0  10       2     300
1  20       3     200
```

**Edit:**

```
df[['n_ratings','av_rating']]=df[['Id','title']].join(df.groupby(['Id','title']).agg({'rating':'count','rating2':'mean'}), on=['Id','title'])[['rating','rating2']]
print(df.drop_duplicates(keep='last',subset='Id'))
```

Comment: Aha! I inadvertently read the second answer first and so asked them how to achieve this from their code. Thank you for showing me how to pipe/string together `groupby().agg().rename()`.

Comment: I'm getting an error/warning: `FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`
  `return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @KarlBaker Now, sorry for late reply, hope it does not do the warning again.

Comment: In simplifying my df in my original post I did not show other columns that I wish to keep. Running your code adds the 2 new cols as desired and correctly deletes `case` and `value`, but also deletes other cols I wish to keep. Is there a parameter to control this behavior? I tried adding `'col5':'col5'` to the rename dict but it did not work so I suspect it has to do with the `agg` function. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited my original post as I see what I need is slightly different than I thought.

Comment: @KarlBaker sorry for being late again, i edited mine.

Comment: no apology needed, I really appreciate your help. I've been reading through the `groupby` documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html and had not figured this out.

Comment: So do I need to explicitly name every column I want to retain in the groupby list? Or is there an easier way? I ask because the df could have dozens or hundreds of variables, making that impractical. Side note: To get your updated code to work I had to remove the `axis=1`, else this error: `"TypeError: Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'."` Thanks again!

Comment: @KarlBaker Now the second one is updated, see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185899/discussion-between-u9-forward-and-karl-baker).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'case': [1,2,3,4,6],
                             'id': [10,10,20,20,20],
                             'value':[100,500,300,150,150],
                             })

df['n_vals'] = df.groupby(['id'])['id'].transform('count')
df['av_val'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform('mean')

print (df)
#   case  id  value  n_vals  av_val
#0     1  10    100       2   300.0
#1     2  10    500       2   300.0
#2     3  20    300       3   200.0
#3     4  20    150       3   200.0
#4     6  20    150       3   200.0
```

In this way, you get to keep every row and see their `n_vals` and `av_val` rather than lose the data using the usual `groupby` `agg` functions

Comment: Not OP's desired output.

Comment: @U9-Forward you're right, but I'm giving a different answer that keeps all the information in case that's what anyone wants to find

Comment: @ycx OP specifically said that that's not what they want. It's not an omission of some sort.

Comment: @ycx, thank you for showing me the `groupby()` and `transform()` functions. That helps me select values from the right rows. How would you go about deleting the extra rows? I was thinking I'd delete rows with `NULL` values in the relevant columns, but with all populated is there a pandas way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: @Karl Baker  you can look into df.dropna(axis=‘columns’) or df[‘value’].dropna() for deletion or fillna for replacement. These will be faster without the for loop. Apologies for lack of formatting as Im on the phone and the tilde button is not on my keyboard. See link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html